# DXA 2.1 XPM Page publishing not happening

Tags: dxa, experience-manager, dxa-2.1

In my DXA 2.1 web application, when I edit the content in XPM, the modified component is saved fine in CMS, but XPM just publishes the component.

As this is not a 'dynamic component', it ends with the warning in the publishing queue. I could see the modified content in CMS but page is still having the old content. If I publish the page manually then everything looks ok. Why XPM is only triggering component publishing? How can I change this behaviour to publishing page instead of component?

Thanks.

Comment: XPM always republishes the component you modified, so this is expected behavior. If the component is embedded on the page, Tridion will effectively publish the page containing the component. The same happens if you publish the component from the GUI. If you see a warning in the queue, something else must be wrong. Do you have any custom resolvers configured perhaps?

Comment: Thanks Quirijn. You are right it was some other issue. I had earlier changed the stage target name to newStage, and XPM was sending component for publishing to Stage target type.